# SQL Server schema evolution (migrations)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, deployment, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-migrations

Talking to production SQL Server applications it's very important to support scenarios allowing to modify database schema during the application life cycle. In my particular case it's **Entity Framework 4.1** application.

Today ADO.NET team works on [Code First Migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/21/code-first-migrations-alpha-3-released.aspx). I think it's really great but it's in alpha stage and can be used only with EF Code First.

What are the best practices to implement such a workflow writing update (up and down) scripts in SQL language for **production use**? Are there any supporting tools?

**Deployment** scenarios are also very important. How to automate migrations on a build server (using MSBuild, for example)?

Comment: You may want to check an alternative EF Code-First migration strategy - [EntityFramework.SchemaCompare](http://github.com/kriasoft/data)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are quite a few - find a [long list of alternatives here](http://flux88.com/2008/06/net-database-migration-tool-roundup/).

I've been looking into this myself, trying to avoid doing any further development on our own, internal home-grown solution (which is a mess....).

The one that I was intrigued about the most is [Roundhouse](http://code.google.com/p/roundhouse/)

It works off SQL scripts (which is a must for me), it allows one-time scripts, everytime scripts and so forth, it keeps track of what it's done, it allows environment-specific scripts (e.g. stuff for your `DEV` or `TEST` environment that you don't want on production), it's highly configurable - looking good to me!

Comment: Also found FluentMigrator (https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator). It's similar to Migrator.NET and really nice.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use plain SQL query for SQL schema migration but it's not easy if you don't have a database version control, If you use .net there is a NuGet Package which is free and will control your database version and it work with plain SQL query.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLMigrationByQuery